# What is the little golden up-arrow in the tank crew part of Garage UI?

Tags: world-of-tanks

The second crew member has this little golden thing next to "91%". I didn't notice anything unusual on his card, nor anything to change or upgrade... I checked the guide and it wasn't mentioned. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is taken from the World of Tanks wiki on the [Crew](http://wiki.worldoftanks.com/Crew) page:

> **Accelerated Crew Training Bonus Option:** For Premium Vehicles and for
>   fully researched Elite Status vehicles, the Player has the option of
>   checking the Accelerate Crew Training box that appears above the crew
>   panel in the garage. Selecting this option directs all experience
>   normally accrued to the vehicle to instead be added to and applied to
>   increasing the crew's Training Levels. The vehicle's experience at the
>   end of each battle is then distributed among the crew members and the
>   crew member with the lowest Training Level will get a double portion.
>   An icon [image]  appears in the crew panel
>   to the left of the crew member who is receiving the double share.
>   Accelerate Crew Training can be toggled on and off at any time via the
>   check box, and each time a dialog box will appear to notify the player
>   that it has now on or off